# Bootstrap layout with mystery pulls and pushes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to make uncommon layout with bootstrap, but pulls and pushes works in wierd way. Look at it:

http://jsfiddle.net/tfgdveop/1/

```
<div class="container" style="background: white">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background: red; height: 300px;">catalog</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9" style="background: blue; height: 50px;">bNNER</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-6" style="background: yellow; height: 500px;">News</div>        
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-3" style="background: green; height: 280px;">Catalog</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6" style="background: pink; height: 100px;">Promo</div>               
  </div>
</div>
```

I need pink promo block 9 cols width, but if i made it wider 6, it fall under news block.

Comment: you included 30 columns in a row. when its 12 maximum for one row.

Comment: why do you think 12 is maximum?

Comment: did you read BS docs? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

Comment: this is exactly what i need. i dont need "a single row" and i need "wrap onto a new line". actually i got it, as you can see in example. but using "push" and "pull" classes makes behavior of block floating unpredictable for me. could you explain why pink block fall under only if it wider 6?

Answer (score 0):

I changed order a bit and Yellow News to float to right. I also removed all unnnecessary pulls and pushes. Here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/tfgdveop/3/

```
<div class="container" style="background: white">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background: red; height: 300px;">catalog</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9"style="background: blue; height: 50px;">bNNER</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-6"style="background: green; height: 280px;">Catalog</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right"style="background: yellow; height: 500px;">News</div>    
 <div class="col-xs-9" style="background: pink; height: 100px;">Promo</div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you are looking for?